# What is residue $g_{2}$ of the generator g in the multiplicative subgroup of order 2? I can't understand what the (b) talk about.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

To bring down $X$ from the group $\mathbb Z^{*}_{p}$ into a subgroup of prime order $q$, we raise $X$ to exponent $\phi(p)/q$ modulo $p$. Here, this means computing $X_{2}$=$X^{1013}\mod 2027$, where the residue $X_{2}$ will be either +1 or -1(mod 2027), as we would expect since the multiplicative group of order $2$ is $\{1,-1\}$. Note however that when computing with positive numbers you'll get $2026$; not $-1$, which is the same since $2026\equiv -1\pmod{2027}$.In other words, the subgroup of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z^{*}_{p}$ is equivalently represented as the set $\{1,2026\}$.

(b)Compute the residue $g_{2}$ of the generator $g$, in the multiplicative group of order $2$. Could you have predicted the value of $g_2$ without doing the calculation, from the fact that you picked $g$ to be the generator of the whole multiplicative group of order $\phi(p)$?

I can't understand how to solve (b). What I think is that:

$g_{2}=g^{\frac{2027-1}{2}}=g^{1013}=?\mod 2027$
Hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: You know $g_2$ is either $1$ or $-1$. Can it be $1$? Think about the order of $g$. For the direct computation, you could use binary exponentiation.

Comment: Could you give more help, I was confused about this.

Comment: Well, $g$ has order $2026$ because it’s a generator. So is it possible that $g^{1013}=1$?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation！